# Flutter Change Notifier dispose individual listener

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently adding a listener to a screen like this:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    person.addListener(() {
      doSomething();
    });

    super.initState();
  }
```

This works, but I have difficulties with correctly disposing the listener after I will call Navigator pop.

I tried calling dispose

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    person.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

But this disposes all the listeners on "person". Which are active on other parts in the app.

Is there a possibility to assign a key to the addListener and dispose only that addListener?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could say `person.removeListener(yourListener)` in your `dispose` method

Comment: Thanks! How can I define yourListener ?

Comment: Create a function from the body that you have up in your `initState` 
example `void myListener() {
    // do your things
  }` and pass that reference to your `addListener` in `initState` and to `removeListener` in `dispose`